# Oracle 10g & PowerShell - How to create hashed password

Tags: oracle, powershell, oracle10g, password-hash

I have a PowerShell script that will create a new Oracle user. The code is correct, and the user is created as expected. My only problem is replicating Oracle's password hashing.

I'd like to have the ability to hash the password in PowerShell using the same algorithm as Oracle 10g and then insert the hashed password into Oracle using this code.  `IDENTIFIED BY VALUES 'NEED TO INSERT HASHED PASSWORD`'.

Here's an example of a current password in the database:  `IDENTIFIED BY VALUES '033348433385A2DE'`

I tried a few things in PowerShell but couldn't get it to work. According to my understanding, Oracle uses the username & password combination to generate the hashed value, among other things. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

This is the code I'm currently using. It establishes an Oracle connection and then inserts the required information.

```
$login_newname = 'SomeName'
    
$query_user =  CREATE USER $login_newname
      IDENTIFIED BY VALUES 'NEED TO INSERT HASHED PASSWORD'
      DEFAULT TABLESPACE USER_DATA
      TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMPORARY_DATA
      PROFILE DEFAULT
      ACCOUNT UNLOCK"

$connectionstring = "User Id = $username;Password = $password;Data Source = $datasource"
$con = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(“$connectionString”)
$con.open()
$cmd=$con.CreateCommand()



$query_user_1 = "GRANT CONNECT TO $login_newname WITH ADMIN OPTION"
$query_user_2 = "GRANT RESOURCE TO $login_newname WITH ADMIN OPTION"
$query_user_3 = "GRANT ALL_ACCESS TO $login_newname WITH ADMIN OPTION"
$query_user_4 = "ALTER USER $login_newname DEFAULT ROLE CONNECT, RESOURCE"
$query_user_5 = "GRANT SELECT ANY TABLE TO $login_newname WITH ADMIN OPTION"
$query_user_6 = "GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO $login_newname WITH ADMIN OPTION"


$cmd.CommandText=$query_user 
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() | Out-Null
$cmd.CommandText=$query_user_1
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() | Out-Null
$cmd.CommandText=$query_user_2
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() | Out-Null
$cmd.CommandText=$query_user_3
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() | Out-Null
$cmd.CommandText=$query_user_4
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() | Out-Null
$cmd.CommandText=$query_user_5
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() | Out-Null
$cmd.CommandText=$query_user_6
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() | Out-Null
```

Comment: It looks like Oracle's [salting](https://www.trustwave.com/en-us/resources/blogs/spiderlabs-blog/changes-in-oracle-database-12c-password-hashes/) the password. Maybe explain the [root problem](https://xyproblem.info/) you are trying to solve, as your previous (deleted) question was about raw insert on the users table. The thing is, any update in Oracle might break your copy-of-hashing system, so a more durable solution is needed.

Comment: My previous question is not related to this. That was a different database altogether, couldn't create users in that one. It was just inserts into tables. Please ignore that as it was already deleted for this reason.

Comment: It's unclear if you're stuck on the algorithm ([explained here](https://seanstuber.com/how-oracle-stores-passwords/), with a demo PL/SQL implementation), or you understand that but are stuck on using crypto in PowerShell. "I tried a few things" doesn't tell us which part you have an issue with; and the code you posted is everything *except* how you have tried to create the hash value.

Comment: I'd also question why you want to do this - what is the benefit of doing your own hashing rather than just using the plain password in the `create user`? Using `identified by values` is generally only useful for recreating a user when you don't know the password - e.g. migrating users from one DB to another - based on my fading memories of doing this sort of thing many years ago.

Comment: The reason for this script is to create accounts using it and not touch the front-end, which will save me some time as I can pull the necessary details from Active-Directory and drop them in the database directly. Identified by values cannot be blank when creating a new user in Oracle. As for "(explained here, with a demo PL/SQL implementation), or you understand that but are stuck on using crypto in PowerShell." - I don't really know what PowerShell crypto is or how to use that implementation using Powershell. The things I've tried were basically work-arounds and not necessarily hashing.

Comment: Maybe you should use [integrated Windows authentication](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NTQRF/authen.htm#NTQRF120) instead.

Comment: Depending on the version of the database and the `COMPATIBILITY` parameter setting, Oracle may maintain *multiple* hashes for each user, using different algorithms. Using the `IDENTIFIED BY` parameter, which is technically not supported, may result in incompatibility with some client connections. I too would recommend integrated Windows authentication if that's what you're trying to sync with.

Comment: I can't really use 'integrated Windows authentication' as the front end has a form that requires user to login. That should be the only hash. It's quite an old database that is not going to be updated anytime soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find a work-around for anyone that needs to replicate the same functionality.

I have defaulted this line like so  `IDENTIFIED BY VALUES 'password'` .This will now create a user in Oracle with a password of 'password' but it won't apply the hashing.

I had to add an extra line:

```
$query_user_7 = "ALTER USER $login_newname IDENTIFIED BY password(This can be anything, your desired password)"
```

And then execute the query like so:

```
$cmd.CommandText=$query_user_7
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() | Out-Null
```

This will apply Oracle hashing to your new password and will allow you to login.

Please note, this works for Oracle 10g. I have not tried to do this on later Oracle versions.